# Insert data into database from another models view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have two model classes for my project,

```
public class BookModel
{
    public Int64 ISBN { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int? FormatID { get; set; }
    public virtual FormatModel Format { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class FormatModel
{
    public FormatModel()
    {
        Books = new HashSet<BookModel>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookModel> Books { get; }
}
```

I want to create a modal in my `Create.cshtml` file to add a new format if the specified format doesn't exist.

How can I create a Submit button for my modal to add the format in `FormatModel`?

This is my view:

```
@model RookBookMVC.Models.BookModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "/Book/Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Book", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>BookModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FormatID, "FormatID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="input-group col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("FormatID", null, "Select Book Format", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                        Add New
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FormatID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ISBN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ISBN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ISBN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Format", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add New Format</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Format.Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Format.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Format.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create Format" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

after I click on the 'Create Format' button. it returns false for `ModelState.IsValid` and doesn't add any data to my database

What should I do for making 'Create Format' Button make a new Entity for Format and save it in my database?

for Additional I need to create two models via a single page

Comment: You have to either pass the mandatory properties of BookModel as hidden properties or pass parameter with property name on Modal form post.

Comment: @Jaggan_j I need to add format as a new entity and user must have select for Book from a dropdown list, after inserting the new format

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create a View Model and pass the view model property as parameter to the Action - Format/ Create post.
ViewModel property:

```
public string FormatValue { get; set; }
```

Modal view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FormatValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Controller code with parameter as the same name as the view model property being passed from the modal form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string formatValue)
{
  using (var dataContext = new YourDbContextModel())
  {
     FormatModel fmtModel = new FormatModel();
     fmtModel.Value = formatValue;
     // rest of your code to save data
  }                   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I should just pass my Viewmodel to Controller? Does ViewModel Property include Book and FormatValue?

Comment: Not entire ViewModel but just the property as shown above

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MYViewModel{   public string FormatValue { get; set; } }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model MYViewModel

    <div>
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FormatValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
```

Do You Mean something Like that?
OR

```
 public class MYViewModel{   
  public string FormatValue { get; set; } 
  Public BookModel Book {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: ViewModel purpose is more often than not to include multiple models in the same view, so your second one is correct.